# Check a chunk of blocks of a given size for exteriors only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

I've a question on how to optimize a triple for loop which would grant me a huge performance boost.

Let's say I've a chunk of 16x16x16 blocks, so we're talking 3D. I am currently looping every block in the chunk so I have three nested for loops. The thing is I only need the exterior part of the chunk to be iterated over if all blocks in it are rendered. If they are rendered I stop to check blocks for this particular chunk. If they are not all rendered, I do the same operation but for size-2 until size < 2. That would be the perfect way since it would only lookup the parts I need.

To compare iterations, if all blocks of the exterior in a 16x16x16 chunks are rendered that would give us 16^3 - 14^3 = 4096 - 2744 = 1352 blocks to check instead of 4096.

The only way I could think about is create different section for the chunk, so I would check the top part, then the left part, etc.

Thanks for reading

Edit :

Imagine something like this where the cubes are empty. Only the outter part is checked (I don't need help on the checking part. I just don't want to loop the inner part of the cube if the outside is alredy fully rendered)

[image: Cubes]

Comment: So do you have any problem to check for each face? And is this question about c# or unity3d?

Comment: No, in my nested for loops I'm able to check for each face. Well, I'm working with unity and coding in c#. @shingo

Comment: depening of how much 'checking' you are doing, this might not give you that much optimization. What decides if the block is rendered? Can you do a raycast against block surface? its not completetly clear what you want to do

Comment: Well, a block is checking for neighbours to know if it has to render. Therefor each block has to Get the blocks surrounding it and checking if neighbour is rendered. That would give 2744*6 less iterations for the best case. @zambari